# MGF of sample variance

Tags: probability, distributions, moment-generating-function

Let $$s^2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n-1}$$ be the sample variance of a random sample of size $n$ from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. I am trying to derive the mgf of $s^2$ but have probably made a mistake somewhere and cannot figure out where. I am getting $(1-2(\frac{t\sigma^2}{n}))^{-\frac{n}{2}}$ as the mgf.

I started off by finding the pdf of $X-\bar{X}$. I argued that it was normal, specifically $N(0,\frac{(n-1)}{n}\sigma^2)$, since it is a linear combination of normal random variables. The pdf I got for this was $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}}\sigma}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2(\frac{n-1}{n})\sigma^2}}$

After that I calculated the pdf of $(X_i-\bar{X})^2$ by taking $\frac{d}{da}$ $P((X-\bar{X})^2\leq a)$, getting $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}}\sigma\sqrt{a}}e^{\frac{a}{2(\frac{n-1}{n})\sigma^2}}$. Then I found the mgf of this to be $(1-2t\sigma^2(\frac{n-1}{n}))^{-1/2}$.

I then proceeded to calculate the mgf of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2$ which was just a matter of raising the previous mgf to the power of n since they are independent.

Finally I calculated the mgf of $s^2$ by taking the mgf of the previous sum of random variables divided by $n-1$, equivalent to replacing $t$ with $\frac{t}{n-1}$, ending up with $(1-2(\frac{t\sigma^2}{n}))^{-\frac{n}{2}}$.

I will be grateful to anyone who can point to any mistakes.

Comment: Just a suggestion: wouldn't it be far easier to prove that $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n-1}$ and then work out the MGF for a Gamma distribution?

Comment: Please add the [self-study] tag & read its wiki.

Comment: Your error is in assuming all the terms in $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2$ are independent, they are not. You could advance by finding the multinormal distribution of $(X_1-\bar{X},\dots, X_n-\bar{X}$ and going from there (the covariance matrix is **not** diagonal).

Comment: Now I understand why it wasn't working out for me. Thank you.